# ONB of Hilbert dual $H'$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ an arbitrary Hilbert space, $\{ e_i \}_{i \in I}$ ONB of $H$.

1. Is there an ONB $\{ e^j \}_{j \in I}$ of the Hilbert dual $H'$, s.t. $e^j(e_i)=\delta_{ij}$?
2. If so, is $\{e_i \otimes e^j\}_{i,j \in I}$ an ONB of $H \hat{\otimes} H'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let $\Theta \colon H \to H'$ denote the semilinear isometric Riesz isomorphism $\Theta(x) = \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<\cdot,x>$. Then we have, by definition of the inner product in $H'$, that 
   $$ \<\Theta x, \Theta y>_{H'} = \<y,x>_H $$
   Hence, $e^i := \Theta e_i$, $i \in I$, defines an orthonormal basis in $H'$ (to see that it is a basis, note that ${\rm span}\{e^i \mid i \in I\}$ is dense in $H'$ as $\Theta$ is an isomorphism. Moreover 
   $$ e^j(e_i) = (\Theta e_j)(e_i) = \<e_i, e_j>_H = \delta_{ij} $$
2. The set is orthonormal, as
   $$ \<e_i \otimes e^j, e_{i'} \otimes e^{j'}> = \<e_i, e_{i'}>\<e^j, e^{j'}> 
    = \delta_{ii'}\delta_{jj'}$$ 
   and complete due to the definition of the tensor product.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (there is a typo in the dfn of $e^i$)